# Can anyone recommend a good (preferably free) tool to convert files and file contents to RSS?

Tags: rss

I need something that takes a directory's contents and then proceeds to generate an RSS based on what is IN the files in the directory, meaning:

```
/myDir -ls 
.
..
a.xml
b.xml
c.xml
d.txt
```

The mechanism I'm looking for would only look through the files with extension .xml, and would assemble their contents into one larger .xml (or .rss) file that it would spit back out, via HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to have a look into [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/). It is a great utility to let you create, consume and manipulate *ALL* types of feeds be they RSS or ATOM of any version.

A quick article to get you started is [ROME in a Day: Parse and Publish Feeds in Java](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/02/22/rome-parse-publish-rss-atom-feeds-java.html).